# how to Separate one part from all part NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I want to create two variable NSString that one is all and another is a part of first variable. like this :

```
NSString *all = @"john/red/inter/274503/jackat.jpg";
NSString *part = //I want this variable take this value:"jackat.jpg" from all
```

but I dont know this syntax that do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this syntax :

```
NSString *name = [all lastPathComponent];
```

Comment: my friend if I want check extension what I do ? for example I get '.jpg' format from nsstring part

Comment: @david Check the documentation of `NSString`, `NSString *extension = [name pathExtension]`;

Answer (score 2):

The NSString method lastPathComponent will give you the file name and extension.

Comment: my friend if I want check extension what I do ? for example I get '.jpg' format from nsstring part.

Comment: @david, go look at the NSString Class Reference, I'm sure you can find that on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Plese try to use this one ... This string will give you last path string.

```
 NSString *path = [all lastPathComponent];
```

OR

```
NSString *path = [[all componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] lastObject];
```

And you can get your extension using like this..

```
NSLog(@"Format :  %@",[all substringFromIndex:NSMaxRange([all rangeOfString:@"."])]);
```

OR

```
NSLog(@"Path %@",[all pathExtension]);
```

Comment: +1 for being first ;)

Comment: my friend how I check type this file??? (extension : for example I check this file what is type?)

Comment: Dear friend see my edited answer you can get using like this...

Comment: Have you got your answer ?

Comment: @david Why did you accept the other answer after this one helped you out so much?  That seems rude.

Comment: who helped me so much?